# Error while using String.format in Scala - java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'

Tags: scala, split

I am trying to use String.format to replace substring in Scala. I am having substring values in Array[String]

Code below:

```
 val Input_Query = "select * from table where arg_1 = %s and arg_2 = %s"
 val str1 = "2019_09"
 val dbpairs = str1.split("_")
 val query = Input_Query.format(dbpairs)
```

Expected output:
`select * from table where arg_1 = 2019 and arg_2 = 09`

Error:

> java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
> at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2519)
> at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are trying to pass array argument to varargs method `format`.

problem in line:
`val query = Input_Query.format(dbpairs)`

`format` signature is:

`def format(args : Any*): String`

`Any*` means it accepts one or more elements of `Any` type.

your code should be:

```
val Input_Query = "select * from table where arg_1 = %s and arg_2 = %s"
val str1 = "2010_09"
val dbpairs: Array[String] = str1.split("_")
val query = Input_Query.format(dbpairs:_*)
println(query) // select * from table where arg_1 = 2010 and arg_2 = 09
```

when you call varargs method you should pass it with `:_*` syntax, not just passing `Array` or `Seq`.
In your case you can use *string interpolation* also.

useful links:

- [varargs using guide](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-varargs-syntax-function-examples/)
- [string interpolation scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)